# This is used theme / web template?

Tags: templates, web, wordpress-theming, themes, content-management-system

Hello everyone and my respected Masters, I have just been interested in the world of websites and themes but I have one problem with "what do they use or the name of the theme / template?"

I've been using whatcms and wptheme and everything is blocked by cloudflare and also asked the Website Owner and no response. does anyone know the names of the themes/templates they use?

[Links](https://travistranslations.com/)

I'm trying to create a novel translation website for my own pleasure and as a hobby, and I expect to be like one of the websites above (I mean the theme or template) because it looks very good in my eyes and is very friendly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The theme is called Novel if that helps at all.  For future reference, you can find a WP theme by checking the source code; follow the steps on this link:

[https://stnsvn.com/blog/find-wordpress-theme-plugins-site-using#:~:text=You%20can%20also%20find%20a,Plugins%20folder%20under%20WP%2DContent](https://stnsvn.com/blog/find-wordpress-theme-plugins-site-using#:%7E:text=You%20can%20also%20find%20a,Plugins%20folder%20under%20WP%2DContent).

Comment: already following the source code as per the link direction you provided, but style.travis's website css is sort of minified or sort of protected by something.

style.his css is more just one line sentence and very long, but it really helps me thank you very much.

Comment: no theme name, author or anything like that found in styles.css

Comment: if you check here: https://whatwpthemeisthat.com/ it shows that the author is https://github.com/iniznet and name of the theme is Novel. Best of luck!

Comment: I know the name github... maybe a facebook friend or a grub admin. and he's in the same country.

Comment: do you know a theme similar to that website?